# Securing Data In A Python Program At Runtime

Tags: python, c++, security, encryption, reverse-engineering

I am in the process of evaluating whether Python is a suitable implementation choice for my program given the security requirements.

The input to my program is an set of encrypted (RSA) text files that describe some I/P that I want to keep secure. The encryption / decryption library and the private key are all accessed via SWIG wrappers to a C++ library. I envision that the Python code will call the library to decrypt the incoming source files.

Once decrypted, I will transform the I/P in some fashion and then write it out encrypted, once again using the SWIG wrapped C++ library for this function.

My program and the I/P will be distributed to customers, but the customers should not be able to examine the I/P. Only tools designated by the I/P author that have the private key should.

Can someone examine the data in its decrypted state as it flows through my program at run-time? Is there a way to protect my data in Python? Is a C++ implementation more secure than a Python one?

Comment: What's to stop someone from attaching a debugger and examining the program's memory after decryption? Both C++ and Python solutions are vulnerable to this.

Comment: @Aldehir: This would be possible even if the program is stripped of all debug information?

Comment: Sure, even without debug information it's still possible to obtain the decrypted data as it will exist in memory. I will say this, though, I'm assuming you're using python to perform transformations on the decrypted data; if that's the case, then they can modify the python code to print out that decrypted data without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your application contains the private key inside of it, then your data will never truly be safe from a motivated hacker (as they can step through the program to find it)...

Or they could run your app in a debugger, pause it after the files have been decoded in memory and then pull the data from memory.

Comment: Adding up to this answer and answering the OP `Is a C++ implementation more secure than a Python one?`: changing language won't make any difference, since you are give the customers both the encrypted data and the key, there's nothing to stop someone with the motivation, knowledge and time to crack it out.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: Thanks. Then the question is, is the effort involved in getting to the unecrypted data less in interpreted Python or compiled C++? We already have other C++ programs transforming unecrypted versions of the data, so this new feature (either in C++ or Python) should not be the weakest link in the security chain.

Comment: It's probably easier to obfuscate your C++ code to make it harder for someone to decompile... but still not impossible.